# getScript - execute on dialog confirmation

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-dialog, getscript

I have script that when loaded using the traditional standalone method

`<Script src="wthvideo/wthvideo.js"></script>`

works without a problem. But when I attempt to load it using Ajax/getScript() method after click confirmation on a JqueryUi.Dialog box - the script will not run/load and developer tools doesn't show the script getting called.

Other components such as the `fadeIn()` effects trigger just fine - only the `getScript()` fails. Looking at the JqueryUi API i dont see where im implimenting it wrongly, can someone shed some light on why the script won't load/fire?

```
$( "#fsr" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 350,
      width: 550,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Allow Fullscreen": function() {
          launchFullscreen(document.documentElement);
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $('#title span').fadeIn(2000);
            $('#titlesub span').fadeIn(2800);
            setTimeout(function(){$('#globe').addClass("globefc");}, 1500);
            /*$.ajax({
            url: "wthvideo/wthvideo.js",
            async: false,
            dataType: "script",
            success: success
            });*/
            $.getScript("wthvideo/wthvideo.js");
            setTimeout(function(){  $('#wthvideo').remove();}, 39500);

        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: If you open the developer tools' Network tab when you first load the page, then get your dialog and click the "Allow Fullscreen" button, do you see a request for your script?  Also, what does `wthvideo.js` actually *DO*?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I do see the GET request on the NET panel when i click the "Allow Fullscreen" button -  wthvideo.js is a custom flash/html 5 fallback video player for a full screen video that plays on entry into the website. It creates a full screen element on the DOM and plays the .mp4 video - problem is, it works when placed outside of the dialog, but inside the dialog, i get the CALL to the script, but no execution

Comment: Have you tried putting a `console.log('testing')` at line #1 of `wthvideo.js`?  The script not working as expected doesn't 100% confirm that it is not actually executing...

Comment: @AlexMcMillan it outputs to the console properly... is it possible that a JqueryUi.dialog affects the DOM, there fore the script is executing but not attaching properly to the DOM element(s) it's supposed to? I wouldn't think a dialog() does anything to the DOM elements.

Comment: So the script *is* executing, but not working?  Are you able to provide a link to `wthvideo.js`?

Comment: @AlexMcMillan want to make a SO chat room and i'll let you look at it that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99984/discussion-between-alex-mcmillan-and-dmsjax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script (`wthvideo.js`) takes on the form:

```
function wthplayer() {
  ...
}

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", wthplayer, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", wthplayer);
} else {
    window.onload = wthplayer;
}
```

So, you are only doing 2 things:

1. Defining a function
2. Telling the browser to execute the function when the "onload" event fires.

Your problem is that you are dynamically loading the `wthvideo.js` script *long after the browsers `onLoad` event has fired*.  This works fine if you are loading the script *prior* to the `onLoad` event, which is why you have no problem when using a `<script>` tag.

There are many ways to fix this.  One quick way is to [check if the `onLoad` event has already executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15570139/has-window-onload-event-already-fired) and execute your function immediately like so:

```
function wthplayer() {
  ...
}

if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
  wthplayer();
}
else {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", wthplayer, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", wthplayer);
  } else {
    window.onload = wthplayer;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked, i didnt write the wthvideo.js it came with the video production so i didn't go far into the code. But i do see the problem, thanks for finding it.